# Disable IE browser cache on Windows Phone 8

Tags: internet-explorer

Is it possible to disable the cache in Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 8?

Kinda annoying to go to settings/delete history/delete <-back each time while developing.

Comment: Hey, looks like it is an specific Dev question. I think it can be better answered on Stack Overflow. What do you think?

Comment: @VitorCanova No it's not - it's a basic browser setting same as in any desktop browser what I was asking for. Also we migrate all WP related questions from SO to WP SE, so no need to clutter up on SO.

Comment: But I'm sure there is a better solution for a non user perspective. You did wrote "while developing", it triggers me. ;)

Comment: @VitorCanova Yeah - sorry - what I was looking for was a simple default browser setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no developer options available such as disabling the cache on a Windows Phone 8 device.

You could [try sending the various **cache-control** HTTP headers or **no-cache/expires** HTML META tags](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) and see if that works instead?